# How to set dll search path in Fortran?

Tags: search, dll, fortran

is there a way to set the external dll searching path when a Fortran project is deployed(Leave the PATH strategy aside)?
Assume that we have a Main.exe here, and it depend on an external dll called Depend.dll. Generally, we can put Main.exe and Depend.dll together under the same folder to make it work, but in another situation, if Depend.dll is under a folder called External, and External and Main.exe are put together, is there a solution that Main.exe can find the dll?

Comment: Which operating system? How would you do it with an executable created in another language (as the same would apply for Fortran)?

Comment: Windows for now. The Windows API SetDllDirectory may work, but I want to seek if there is an easier way like if we can do some configuration in VS and the generated code can auto directly search External folder ?

Comment: For Windows I think the easiest way would be to add the directory where the dll resides to the PATH.

Comment: Is there any approach that can dynamically adds it to PATH when start and removes it when exit ?

Comment: Wrap the executable in a `.bat` file, saving the PATH, adding the dll directory to the PATH, run the executable reset the PATH to the saved PATH.

Comment: OK, I'll try, thanks Albert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed, for Windows:

- add the place of the dll to the `PATH` variable.

In case one wants to only set the path to the `dll` temporarily:

- create a `.bat` file with:

  - save current path: `set SAVED_PATH=%PATH%`
  - set path including dll directory: `set PATH=<path to dll>;%PATH%`
  - `<run executable>`
  - reset path: `set PATH=%SAVED_PATH%`